# Replace text node with element if text match in the document BaseX

Tags: xquery, basex, xquery-3.0, xquery-3.1

I am trying to replace text node with element if document matches that text, below query I have tried but it is giving error "Target is not an element, text, attribute, comment or pi"  below is my query.

inputXML:

```
<book>
<p>Isn't it lovely here? Very smart. We'll be like three queens when you've finished with us,
    Edie. You doing well then?</p>
<p>
    <name type="person">April De Angelis</name>’ plays include <title type="work">Positive
        Hour</title> (Out of Joint) <title type="work">Playhouse Creatures</title> (<name
        type="org">Sphinx Theatre Company</name>), <title type="work">Hush</title> (<name
        type="org">Royal Court</name>), <title type="work">Soft Vengeance</title>, <title
        type="work">The Life and Times of Fanny Hill</title> (adapted from the <name type="org"
        >John Cleland novel</name>) and <title type="work">Ironmistress</title>. Her work for
    radio includes <title>The Outlander</title> (<name type="org">Radio 5</name>), which won the
        <name type="org">Writers’ Guild Award</name> (<date>1992</date>), and, for opera, <title
        type="work">Flight</title> with composer <name type="person">Jonathan Dove</name> (<name
        type="place">Glyndebourne</name>, <date>1998</date>).</p>
 </book>
```

Expected output:

```
<book>
<p>Isn't it lovely here? Very smart. We'll be like three <highlight>>queens</highlight> when
    you've finished with us, Edie. You doing well then?</p>
<p>
    <name type="person">April De Angelis</name>’ plays <highlight>include</highlight>
    <title type="work">Positive Hour</title> (Out of Joint) <title type="work">Playhouse
        Creatures</title> (<name type="org">Sphinx Theatre Company</name>), <title type="work"
        >Hush</title> (<name type="org">Royal Court</name>), <title type="work">Soft
        Vengeance</title>, <title type="work">The Life and Times of Fanny Hill</title> (adapted
    from the <name type="org">John Cleland novel</name>) and <title type="work"
        >Ironmistress</title>. Her work for radio includes <title>The Outlander</title> (<name
        type="org">Radio 5</name>), which won the <name type="org">Writers’ Guild Award</name>
        (<date>1992</date>), and, for opera, <title type="work">Flight</title> with composer
        <name type="person">Jonathan Dove</name> (<name type="place">Glyndebourne</name>,
        <date>1998</date>).</p>
</book>
```

I am using BaseX version 9.5.1 below is the code.

```
let $body := <indexedterms>
        <content>
            <terms>
                <term>include</term>
                <term>Queens</term>
            </terms>
            <uri>/IEEE/IEEE/test.xml</uri>
        </content>
     </indexedterms>

for $contents in $body/content
let $uri := $contents/uri
let $doc := fn:doc($uri)
for $selectedterm in $contents/terms/term/string()
let $Modifieddoc := copy $c := $doc
                    modify
                       (
                          for $nodes in $c//*//text()[fn:matches(.,$selectedterm)]/parent::*
                          return
                          if($nodes/node()[fn:matches(.,$selectedterm)]/parent::*:highlight)
                          then ()
                          else
                          replace node  $nodes/$selectedterm with <highlight>{$selectedterm}</highlight>
                       )
                   return $c
return                       
db:replace('IEEE',substring-after($uri,'/IEEE'),$Modifieddoc)
```

Previously I was using the "replace node  $nodes/node()[fn:contains(.,$selectedterm)] with {$selectedterm} " instead of "replace node  $nodes/$selectedterm with {$selectedterm}" it was doing the work but where terms like steam e.g.(include, includes) so it was matching the both words which is not correct so I have changed the code to "replace node "$nodes/$selectedterm with {$selectedterm}"

Comment: Can Anyone please suggest how can i achieve that.

Comment: @Christian Grün Can you please suggest on that.

Answer (score 0):

`$nodes/$selectedterm` is probably the culprit and most likely not what you want as the `$selectedterm` variable is a sequence of string values (you bind `for $selectedterm in $contents/terms/term/string()`). It might help us understand what you want to achieve if you show us a sample document you load with the `doc` function and the update you want to do on that with BaseX, for instance, for the two sample `term`s you have shown in your code snippet.

Your task of identifying and wrapping search terms in your text contents can be done nicely in XSLT 3 or 3 which you can run with BaseX if you put Saxon 9.9 or 10 or 11 on the class path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="terms" as="xs:string*" select="'include', 'Queens'"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="p//text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., string-join($terms, '|'), 'i')/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:match">
    <highlight>{.}</highlight>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:non-match">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As the used `analyze-string` function exists also in BaseX/XQuery you should also be able to use XQuery update on the result calling that function, i.e. by replacing `fn:match` elements with `highlight` elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Martin Basically what i want whatever element <term> contains text i want to search in the document and tagged with element <highlight> e.g. input parameter: <term>include</term> output: <highlight>include</highlight>

Comment: input snippet : <p>
    <name type="author">martin douglas</name>’ basket include <title>life race</title><title>stress</title>. stress 
    includes</p>

Comment: @DharmendraKumarSingh, please add the details about the sample not only as a comment but by editing your question and adding the samples in a well formatted way.

Comment: I have added the input and output sample so if you see the output xml text "include" and text "queens" has been tagged with element <highlight> and the output xml will be written into DB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion, I will try your approach